# Should I share GCP Artifact Registry instances between different stages like production and test?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I'm setting up an application in GCP.
For the application resources I plan to create separate [Projects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/projects) in GCP for the stages.  E.g. for databases, backend services. I plan to start with a production stage and a non productive stage, e.g. development.

I would like to store the docker images of our backend services in [GCP Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry).

Should I create two separate Artifact Registry instances, one for each stage? Or should I use a shared one and deploy the same image to production that was tested before on non productive stages? Are there best pracies for this?

Comment: This is more of an opinion question, which is off topic here. But we normally have 1 registry per project, with 3 projects (test/uat/production) and a local registry to facilitate easier copying (no need for accounts that have registry roles in 2 separate projects). The image is first built on the local registry, then copied to test, and then later copied from local to uat/prod. If we didn't have a local repo we would copy from test->uat->prod. This is not necessarily best practice (hence a comment), just saying what we do.

Comment: I was hoping for some best practice documentation from Google or other sources. But I guess there is none.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer having a dedicated GCP project with artifact registry repositories, shared accross all other projects.

A SA of the project that hosts registries can publish images and packages (Python for example).

The SA of other projects are only readers of the registries in the other project.

When we work with `Nexus` repo for example, we don't have a repo per env (dev, uat, prd).
We have a shared repo and we can generate snapshot intermediate versions for testing purpose in a dev environement.

I use the same principle for Artifact registry.